# how to turn off logging for Test Stack White?

Tags: white-framework

White is outputting a lot of logs to the Console and I want to turn it off to see my output. How is it possible? I tried the below but still see logs. Is there more code that needs to be added?

```
void func()
{
    CoreAppXmlConfiguration.Instance.LoggerFactory = new WhiteDefaultLoggerFactory(LoggerLevel.Off);

    // Open application and perform actions...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code above seems to be working now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **ConsoleFactory** instead of WhiteDefaultLoggerFactory.

```
CoreAppXmlConfiguration.Instance.LoggerFactory = new ConsoleFactory(LoggerLevel.Error)
```

Comment: Doesn't help.  Even assigning it to your own factory that creates your own logger that does NOTHING in any of the methods STILL causes console to be logged to.